# How to start a stripe free trial period before charging the credit card?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to offer the user a 7 day free trial before they get charged.
I put the trial period of 7 days in the plan. However, it charges the user instantly.

I also tried passing in the argument like this

```
  const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_key");
  if (planType === "monthly") {
    stripe.subscriptions.create(
      {
        customer: customer,
        items: [
          {
            plan: "plan...."
          }
        ],
        coupon: coupon
        trial_end : 1579313395
      },
      function(err, subscription) {
        addDataToUserProfile(uid, "subscription", subscription);
      }
    );
  } else if (planType === "1year") {
    stripe.subscriptions.create(
      {
        customer: customer,
        items: [
          {
            plan: "plan......."
          }
        ],
        coupon: coupon
      },
      function(err, subscription) {
        addDataToUserProfile(uid, "subscription", subscription);
      }
    );
  } else {
    console.log("invalid plan type selected");
  }
};
```

This results in payment failure. Then i call it in this function.

```
exports.addStripeID = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_key");
  const uid = data.uid;
  const source = data.source;
  const email = data.email;
  const planType = data.planType;
  const coupon = data.coupon;
  return stripe.customers
    .create({
      source: source,
      email: email
    })
    .then(
      customer => {
        addCustomerToPlan(customer.id, uid, planType, coupon);
        addData(uid, "stripeID", customer.id);
        return { success: true };
      },
      err => {
        console.log("the error", err);
        return { error: err, message: "there was an error", success: false };
      }
    )
});
```

This is how i call it in firebase.

```
doAddStripeID(source, email, uid, planType, coupon) {
  console.log("do add stripe ID local function called");

  //change to this.functions
  var addData = app.functions().httpsCallable("addStripeID");

  addData({ source: source, email: email, uid: uid, planType: planType, coupon: coupon})
    .then(function (result) {
      console.log("add stripe result is ", result);
      // this.doAddDataToUser(uid, result.key, result.value)
      if (result.data.success) {
        console.log("it works");

        //this can probably be fixed with a reload instead of a interval
        setInterval(() => { window.location.assign("/payment-success") }, 3000);
      } else {
        console.log("nope");
        setInterval(() => { window.location.assign("/payment-failure") }, 3000);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.code);
    });
}
```

Comment: You've included two calls to `stripe.subscriptions.create`, which one results in immediate charging (or do both)?

Comment: If you're actually passing the `trial_end` and the timestamp is in the future, that should cause it to have a trial and not immediately charge.  Have you confirmed in your Dashboard that that's actually what's happening?

Comment: @HenryWoody Both result into immediate charge.

Comment: @floatingLomas Yes i have

Comment: You should probably write into Support with details like the Subscription ID, etc so they can look into the details for you: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i was posting the `trial_end` argument in mili seconds. After dividing it by a 1000 and using `parseInt` it worked just fine. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Do we need to create separate subscription.create instances for regular and trial transactions?

Comment: No you can use the existing instances.